# Google Adwords API: INVALID_TOKEN_HEADER when using new API and correct Developer Token (i believe)

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am having an issue with Google Adwords API and can't seem to get it to work.

I have taken the following steps:

- Installed composer
- Installed Google Adwords API
- Created a Developer Token
- Created Oauth2
- Created a Refresh Token
- Updated all of the above inside of adsapi_php which is in the root
- I also have Basic access to the API

```
<?php
namespace Google\AdsApi\Examples\AdWords\v201809\Reporting;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\ReportDefinitionReportType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\ReportDefinitionService;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;

/**
 * This example gets the fields available in a campaign report.
 */
class GetReportFields
{

    const PAGE_LIMIT = 500;

    public static function runExample(
        AdWordsServices $adWordsServices,
        AdWordsSession $session
    ) {
        $reportDefinitionService = $adWordsServices->get($session, ReportDefinitionService::class);

        // The type of the report to get fields for.
        $reportType = ReportDefinitionReportType::CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT;

        // Get report fields of the report type.
        $reportDefinitionFields = $reportDefinitionService->getReportFields($reportType);

        printf(
            "The report type '%s' contains the following fields:\n",
            $reportType
        );
        foreach ($reportDefinitionFields as $reportDefinitionField) {
            printf(
                '  %s (%s)',
                $reportDefinitionField->getFieldName(),
                $reportDefinitionField->getFieldType()
            );
            if ($reportDefinitionField->getEnumValues() !== null) {
                printf(
                    ' := [%s]',
                    implode(', ', $reportDefinitionField->getEnumValues())
                );
            }
            print "\n";
        }
    }

    public static function main()
    {
        // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential for authentication.
        $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->fromFile()->build();

        // Construct an API session configured from a properties file and the
        // OAuth2 credentials above.
        $session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())->fromFile()->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)->build();
        self::runExample(new AdWordsServices(), $session);
    }
}

GetReportFields::main();
?>
```

But I am receiving the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\ApiException: [QuotaCheckError.INVALID_TOKEN_HEADER @ ; trigger:'New developers must use the Google Ads API: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start'] in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\googleads\googleads-php-lib\src\Google\AdsApi\Common\Util\Reflection.php:43 Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\googleads\googleads-php-lib\src\Google\AdsApi\Common\Util\Reflection.php(43): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array) 
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\googleads\googleads-php-lib\src\Google\AdsApi\Common\AdsSoapClient.php(203): Google\AdsApi\Common\Util\Reflection->createInstance('Google\\AdsApi\\A...', Array) 
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\googleads\googleads-php-lib\src\Google\AdsApi\Common\AdsSoapClient.php(165): Google\AdsApi\Common\AdsSoapClient->parseApiExceptionFromSoapFault(Object(SoapFault)) 
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\googleads\googleads-php-lib\src\Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\ReportDefinitionService.php(89): Google\AdsApi\Common\AdsSoapClient->__soapCall('getReportFields', Array) 
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\adwords.php(31): Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\ReportDefinitionService->getReportFields('CAMPAIGN_PERFOR...') 
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\adwords.php(61): Google\AdsApi\Examples\AdWords\v201809\Reporting\GetReportFields::runExample(Object(Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices), Object(Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSession)) 
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\adwords.php(65): Google\AdsApi\Examples\AdWords\v201809\Reporting\GetReportFields::main() 
#7 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\googleads\googleads-php-lib\src\Google\AdsApi\Common\Util\Reflection.php on line 43
```

Now I am certain the credentials are all correct. Inside of https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/common-errors#QuotaCheckError.INVALID_TOKEN_HEADER it states there are only two potential issues:

- The developer token is not set on the request or it contains a typo.
- The namespace of the headers in the request is not correct.

So the only issue could be the namespace of the headers but I do not understand how to: "Ensure that the headers of the request are in the namespace [https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/{version}](https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/%7Bversion%7D), where {version} is replaced with the version of the API being used."

Where do I find the version to confirm if this is the issue or if it is somehow that I am using the wrong API which a new developer tokens are unable to be used on: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/signup? Although I did follow the new documentation to the letter...

Or is it that it is unable to find the adsapi_php? Thus it is always wrong? Any advice for finding out where the issues lies? I have been trying to troubleshoot this since 10am this morning.

If it helps here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "A web interface for MySQL and MariaDB",
    "keywords": ["phpmyadmin","mysql","web"],
    "homepage": "https://www.phpmyadmin.net/",
    "support": {
        "forum": "https://www.phpmyadmin.net/support/",
        "issues": "https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues",
        "wiki": "https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/",
        "docs": "https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/",
        "source": "https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin"
    },
    "license": "GPL-2.0-only",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "The phpMyAdmin Team",
            "email": "developers@phpmyadmin.net",
            "homepage": "https://www.phpmyadmin.net/team/"
        }
    ],
    "non-feature-branches": ["RELEASE_.*"],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "PhpMyAdmin\\": "libraries/classes"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "PhpMyAdmin\\Tests\\": "test/classes",
            "PhpMyAdmin\\Tests\\Selenium\\": "test/selenium/"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://www.phpmyadmin.net"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3 || ^8.0",
        "ext-hash": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-mysqli": "*",
        "ext-pcre": "*",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^3.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "google/gax": "^1.7",
        "google/recaptcha": "^1.1",
        "googleads/google-ads-php": "^10.1",
        "googleads/googleads-php-lib": "^53.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
        "nikic/fast-route": "^1.3",
        "phpmyadmin/motranslator": "^5.0",
        "phpmyadmin/shapefile": "^2.0",
        "phpmyadmin/sql-parser": "^5.0",
        "phpmyadmin/twig-i18n-extension": "^3.0",
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "^2.0",
        "react/http": "^1.4",
        "spatie/crawler": "^7.0",
        "symfony/config": "^4.4.9",
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "^4.4.9",
        "symfony/expression-language": "^4.4.9",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "^1.17.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "^1.17.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.9 || ^3",
        "williamdes/mariadb-mysql-kbs": "^1.2"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "phpseclib/phpseclib": "2.0.8",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "<6.2",
        "pragmarx/google2fa": "<6.1.0 || >8.0",
        "pragmarx/google2fa-qrcode": "<1.0.1",
        "samyoul/u2f-php-server": "<1.1"
    },
    "suggest": {
        "ext-openssl": "Cookie encryption",
        "ext-curl": "Updates checking",
        "ext-opcache": "Better performance",
        "ext-zlib": "For gz import and export",
        "ext-bz2": "For bzip2 import and export",
        "ext-zip": "For zip import and export",
        "ext-gd2": "For image transformations",
        "ext-mbstring": "For best performance",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "For PDF support",
        "pragmarx/google2fa-qrcode": "For 2FA authentication",
        "samyoul/u2f-php-server": "For FIDO U2F authentication"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "php-webdriver/webdriver": "^1.11",
        "phpmyadmin/coding-standard": "^2.1.1",
        "phpstan/extension-installer": "^1.1",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.79",
        "phpstan/phpstan-phpunit": "^0.12.17",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5 || ^8.0 || ^9.0",
        "pragmarx/google2fa-qrcode": "^1.0.1",
        "samyoul/u2f-php-server": "^1.1",
        "symfony/console": "^4.4",
        "symfony/finder": "^4.4",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "^4.4",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.4.1",
        "vimeo/psalm": "^4.7.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
        "firebase/php-jwt": "^3.0"
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "5.2.x-dev"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "phpcbf": "phpcbf",
        "phpcs": "phpcs",
        "phpstan": "phpstan analyse",
        "psalm": "psalm",
        "phpunit": "phpunit --color=always",
        "test": [
            "@phpcs",
            "@phpstan",
            "@psalm",
            "@phpunit"
        ],
        "update:baselines": "phpstan analyse --generate-baseline && psalm --set-baseline=psalm-baseline.xml",
        "twig-lint": "php scripts/console lint:twig templates --ansi --show-deprecations"
    },
    "config":{
        "sort-packages": true,
        "discard-changes": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there in the error message :)

You're a new developer, but you're using the old API.
The new API is located here: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/start

The official PHP library for this API is located here:
https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/